# ObservableCollection, сортировка на лету

Tags: c#, сортировка, observablecollection

Есть ObservableCollection, которая прибинжена к GridView. Внутри нее объекты, у каждого есть свойство Index. Необходимо при вставке нового элемента проверять его Index и добавлять в соответствии с ним в коллекцию (то есть сортировать). Как это элегантно и быстро делать? Самый простой способ, как мне видится, такой:

```
Collection= new ObservableCollection<Object>(Collection.OrderBy(i => i.Index));
```

Если ли более оптимальные варианты? 
P.S. Будет ли сортировка пузырьком или более оптимальные алгоритмы сортировки работать быстрее, чем этот способ? (Сортировки средствами гуя не рассматриваю)

Comment: Пробовали гуглить "OrderedObservableCollection" ? Сходу находится даже NuGet-пакет с этой штукой.

Comment: Зы. Если вы пересоздаете каждый раз новую коллекцию, `ObservableCollection` вам по сути и не нужна. Главное реализовать `INPC`.

Comment: Как раз таки `OrderBy` - самый оптимальный вариант из всех возможных сортировок, т. е. O(n log n), не стоит заменять его на пузырёк.

Comment: @Nikita, вставка одного значения в уже отсортированную коллекцию имеет сложность `О(n)`, не так ли? Ну и не стоит забывать что о-большое скрывает за собой некоторый постоянный коэффициент, за счет которого при малых n `О(n^2)` может работать быстрее. Я за использование `SortedList<T>` и прокси оболочку с реализацией `INCC`

Comment: Насколько часто происходят вставки/удаления? `Sorted*`-коллекции при каждой вставке будут делать сортировку, что медленно. Обычную коллекцию можно сортировать после вставки большой порции новых данных, что в итоге будет быстрее. @Андрей

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, коллекция хранится в отсортированном виде и при вставке нового элемента выполняет сдвиг остальных. Но, в любом случае, оптимальное решение зависит от того откуда берутся данные и алгоритм их получения.

Comment: Почему бы не взять ListCollectionView и написать свои фильтры с предикатами и блекджеками ?!